# Trying to create a topic regex in Kafka using confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to create a regex for topics using confluent . According to [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-sink-properties) ,I cant give topic and topic regex together ( which makes perfect sense ) , But when I give regex it gives me the following error.

```
Missing required configuration "topic" which has no default value. You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate
```

Following is the properties for the connector :

```
{
  "name": "localMongoSink",
  "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
  "topics.regex": "^digest",
  "connection.uri": "mongodb+srv://nitinkapoor:admin@cluster0.7mxo4.mongodb.net/test",
  "database": "result"
}
```

Really appreciate the inputs .

Best Regards
Nk

Comment: What version of the connector are you using?

Comment: its `mongo-kafka-1.3.0`

Comment: Hi @RobinMoffatt Sorry to pester you , but do you have any suggestions ,I tried with v 1.2 as well